# What is the lowest natural $ n $ for which $ T ^ n (C) $ contains at least $ 2019 $

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

Let $ C $ be the radius disk $ 1 $ centered on the origin of $ \mathbb {R }^2 $ and consider the linear transformation$$ T: \mathbb {R}^2 \to \mathbb {R }^2 $$$$ (x, y) | -> \left (\frac {5x + 3y} {4}, \frac {3x + 5y} {4} \right) $$What is the lowest natural $ n $ for which $ T ^ n (C) $ contains at least $ 2019 $ points $ (a, b) $ with coordinates $ a, b \in \mathbb {Z }^2 $

**Attemp:** The matrix for the linear transformation $T(s)$ is $A = \begin{pmatrix} 5/4 & 3/4 \\ 3/4 & 5/4\end{pmatrix}$. It's easy enough to see that $A^n$ approaches $\begin{pmatrix} a & a \\ a & a\end{pmatrix}$ very quickly . This would mean that only points of the form $(x,x)$ will fit inside the transformed unit disk. Notice that $AA^n \approx \begin{pmatrix}2a & 2a \\ 2a & 2a \end{pmatrix}$ for like
$n \ge 3$ or something.

This would mean that after each transformation, the number of available points integer points would approximately double (fine since we're looking for lowest natural $n$ and hence don't need something super exact). Now it's noticeable that for $A, A^2$ and a *possibly* very small number of other base cases, that we may need to calculate the number of points which lie inside the transformed unit disk on the line $y = x$ and only double after a certain point.

So we pretty much have some number $k$ for $n = 3$ or $n = 2$ and require how many times we need to double it to get $\ge 2019$ which is trivial to solve.

The matrix for the linear transformation $T(s)$ is $A = \begin{pmatrix} 5/4 & 3/4 \\ 3/4 & 5/4\end{pmatrix}$. It's easy enough to see that $A^n$ approaches $\begin{pmatrix} a & a \\ a & a\end{pmatrix}$ very quickly . This would mean that only points of the form $(x,x)$ will fit inside the transformed unit disk. Notice that $AA^n \approx \begin{pmatrix}2a & 2a \\ 2a & 2a \end{pmatrix}$ for like
$n \ge 3$ or something.

This would mean that after each transformation, the number of available points integer points would approximately double (fine since we're looking for lowest natural $n$ and hence don't need something super exact). Now it's noticeable that for $A, A^2$ and a *possibly* very small number of other base cases, that we may need to calculate the number of points which lie inside the transformed unit disk on the line $y = x$ and only double after a certain point.

So we pretty much have some number $k$ for $n = 3$ or $n = 2$ and require how many times we need to double it to get $\ge 2019$ which is trivial to solve.

Is this solution correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but there's a lot of "approximate" handwaving in your presentation of it.

You can get it back on firmer ground by noticing that $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ are eigenvectors for $T$ with eigvenvalues $2$ and $1/2$, respectively. This means that if you rotate the coordinate system by 45°, the matrix will diagonalize to
$$ \begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/2 \end{pmatrix} $$
which tells you that the length of the intersection between $T^n(C)$ and the $x=y$ diagonal *exactly* doubles for each step of $T$, right from the beginning. And all points *outside* the diagonal will be gone already from $T^1(C)$.

Going back to the original coordinate system, it is now easy to see that there are
precisely $ 1 + 2 \lfloor 2^n / \sqrt2 \rfloor $ lattice points on the diagonal inside $T^n(C)$, and it is indeed easy to find out when that exceeds $2019$.